# Remove all files created before a certain date

Tags: shell, files, find, ksh

I have a directory containing a high number of files (like logs for every day of the year).
I would like to remove all files created before let's say 22/11. How can I achieve that ? Must I use `find` then exec `-rm`? I'm using ksh.

Comment: The usual caveat is that Unix filesystems don't generally contain a record of when the file was *created* - only the times that  the inode and the content were *last modified* are available.

Answer (score 42):

Using `find` is still the preferred way of deleting files. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for more.

One way of doing this is to create a file with the time-stamp in it. e.g

```
touch -t 201311220000 /tmp/timestamp
```

Now delete the files GNU`find` (assuming in the current directory) that match the time-stamp e.g:

```
find . -type f ! -newer /tmp/timestamp -delete
```

or non GNU find

```
find . -type f ! -newer /tmp/timestamp -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: What about this ? Does it work ? find -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;

Comment: @user1058398 That will delete files older than 5 days from now.

Comment: Does it also delete folder along with files? @val0x00ff

Comment: @Avatar no because the `type -f` limits the action to the files only.

Answer (score 36):

With GNU or some BSD `find`s:

```
find . ! -newermt 2013-11-22 ! -type d -delete
```

Note that it checks the last modification time of the files. On some BSDs, you can use `-newerBt` in place of `-newermt` to check the file's inode *birth* time if available instead.

Note that it will also delete the files created at 2013-11-22 00:00:00.0000000000 exactly, not that any clock is that precise anyway, but that could cause problems for files whose timestamp has been arbitrary set, such as with `touch -d 2013-11-22T00:00:00 some-file` (or `touch -d 2013-11-22` with some `touch` implementation). You could always change it to `! -newermt '2013-11-21 23:59:59.999999999999'` (GNU) or `! -newermt '2013-11-21 23:59:59'` (BSDs, though that would miss the files last modified within the last second of 2013-11-21).

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mtime +<number of days> -name '<file name>' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

example:

```
find /Netap_fileshare_backup/SQL/DB_backups/xeo/ -mtime +15 -name 'ORA_XEO*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

In this case it will remove all files that start whith "ORA_XEO" with more than 15 days.

Comment: Though better watch it with the `rm -rf`, the first command would remove everything contained in any directories that are older than those 15 days. (Also, why the parenthesis around `-name`?)

Comment: You're right, we dont need to put "\("  "\)".

Comment: but if we want to add a condition it can be usefull. for example if we want to remove all files that ends with ".jar" or ".cp", and start with "ex".

`example.jar` - it will be removed
`example.cp` - it will be removed

`example.tar` - it wont be removed

Comment: in this case we can use: `find /path/to/directory/ -mtime +<number of days> \( -name '*.jar' -o -name '*.cp' \) -name 'ex*' -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: That will remove some files from the _<number of days>_ rather than all files older than _<number of days>_ unless you run it exactly at midnight and it finishes within a second. With GNU `find` you should use the `-daystart` modifier to coerce the `-mtime` value to midnight.

Comment: yes thanks. In my case i run this with crontab at all sundays at midnight so i dont have problem with the hour.
but thanks anyway -daystart its a good tip to use!