# How to zip/tar files older than 30 days in archive directories?

Tags: linux, bash, files, date, archive

I am very new to bash scripting, so bear with me, please. I need to collect, compress and delete files in the archive directory of a directory tree older than 30 days old for each respective folder. The directory structure looks like this ...

```
root
-export
--client01
---archive
-process
--client01
---834
----archive
---835
----archive
---837
----archive
```

In each archive folder I need to create timestamped tar/zip with files 30 days or older in the tar/zip file before I delete them (i.e., `20190730_111543.zip`)

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what **each respective folder** encompasses, is that just the *numbered* directories under `--client01`?

Comment: each respective folder = each archive folder. So, in the archive folder under process/client01/834 the script should go into the folder, find files 30 days and older, compress them into a zip/tar and then delete the files (leaving just the compressed file).

Comment: Does that include the already present archives? What are the criteria there?

Comment: @LucasDavenport have you seen this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102752/remove-all-files-created-before-a-certain-date/102767#102767  Also you might want to use `tree dirname` to show the tree structure of the named directory

Comment: so far, I've come up with the following code, but it doesn't traverse through the directories as I expected - it only creates an tar.gz in one folder . . .name=$(date '+%Y%m%d')

for dir in $(find . -type d -iname 'archive'); do 
 cd $dir 
 find . -type f ! -iname '*.tar.gz' -mtime +28 | tar -czvf "$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').tar.gz" --null -T -;
done