# Portable way of finding files whose birth date is after a given timestamp

Tags: find, timestamps, posix, stat, portability

According to [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file/91200#91200), in Linux filesystems, such as ext4, Btrfs and JFS, [that store the file creation time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time) (aka birth time), it is possible to display the file birth time (in human-readable format) with the following command

```
stat -c '%w' approved-images.txt
2019-12-04 16:50:21.539553500 +0000
```

(Note that on Linux this requires [`coreutils` 8.31, `glibc` 2.28 and kernel version 4.11 or newer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119699/43779).)

But the POSIX standard only defines [three distinct timestamps](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_09) to be stored for each file: the time of last data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file status last changed.

Also in the [POSIX standard of `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47), there is no mention of the creation date of files.

For filesystems that store the creation date, is there a way of finding files whose birth date is after a given timestamp in a way that works in bash, dash and zsh shells??

Edit: As commented by [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp), in [Is there really no way in Linux to get creation time for files on cifs/smb share?](https://superuser.com/questions/703768/is-there-really-no-way-in-linux-to-get-creation-time-for-files-on-cifs-smb-share/703927#703927) and [Is there still no Linux kernel interface to get file creation date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304779/is-there-still-no-linux-kernel-interface-to-get-file-creation-date) there already have been extensive discussions related with this question.

And, as commented by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas), in [Remove all files created before a certain date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102752/remove-all-files-created-before-a-certain-date) is stated that some BSDs have `find -newerBt` to check the file's inode birth time.

Comment: I think you might need to define "portable" here. Do you mean "portable to any system that can handle one of these file systems", so any *nix machine, or do you mean "portable across Linux distributions"?

Comment: @terdon Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer the question: is this about portability to any *nix or only across Linux? Since you mention `coreutils`, and kernel versions, for instance, which are a Linux thing. So even if you just want Linux, that will still be limited to those systems with the right versions, which would make it non-portable again. So please define the scope of the question more clearly.

Comment: POSIX has no birthdate and birthdane is a BSD invention. While BSD has it in `struct stat`, Solaris ZFS has it (under the name `crtime`) in the `extended attributes` and as a result the way to retrieve this value is totally platform dependent.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/703927/38062 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304779/5132 are also related.

Comment: Related: [Remove all files created before a certain date](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102752). some BSDs have `find -newerBt`

Comment: @schily you _also_ have dvorak? (n besides t)

Comment: My `find` clone [bfs](https://github.com/tavianator/bfs) supports file birth times on most platforms that have it available, including Linux and the relevant BSDs.  `-newerBt` isn't implemented but you can create a reference file with `touch -t <timestamp> reference` and then `bfs -newerBm reference`.